# Using React useEffect in a loop to fetch data from an API multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hi I'm new to Node/React, and I'm creating a learning project. It's platform that connects freelancers with nonprofit companies. Users (freelancers), view a list of companies, and click a button to connect to a company. Once this is clicked, the user will have that company added as a relationship in the database. This is working correctly.

Now I'd like users to visit a page and view their "connections", basically all the companies they connected with. In the database, I'm only storing the "companyHandle" in the association table. So `currentUser.connections` would give me an array of companyHandles `['aapl', 'gogl', 'msft']`. So when the user views their connections, I would like to fetch data from the backend API, to retrieve more information about each company (companyName, numEmployees, etc..).

I tried to do that by looping through all the companyHandles, and fetching data from the API for each company, but I get the error `React Hook "useEffect" may be executed more than once. Possibly because it is called in a loop..`.

What's a better way to do this? How can I fetch data for different companies? Below is my code (shortened)

**schema**

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
  company_handle VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
  password TEXT NOT NULL,
  company_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  country TEXT NOT NULL,
  num_employees INTEGER CHECK (num_employees > 0)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  username VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
  password TEXT NOT NULL,
  first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  email TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (position('@' IN email) > 1)
);

CREATE TABLE connections (
  username VARCHAR(25)
    REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
  company_handle VARCHAR(25)
    REFERENCES companies ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (username, company_handle)
);
```

**UserConnections.js**

```
function UserConnections() {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const connections = currentUser.connections;
  const [companies, setCompany] = useState([]);

  if (connections) {
    for (const connection in connections) {
      useEffect(function getCompanyDetail() {
        async function getCompany() {
          setCompany(await VolunteerApi.getCurrentCompany(connection));
        }
        getCompany();
      }, [connection]);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {companies.length
        ? (
          <div>
            {companies.map(company => (
              <CompanyCard
                key={company.companyHandle}
                companyHandle={company.companyHandle}
                companyName={company.companyName}
                country={company.country}
                numEmployees={company.numEmployees}
              />
            )
            )}

          </div>
        ) : (
          <p>You have no connections</p>
        )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `promise.all` to execute promises (api fetcher) and `useEffect` hook from React.

```
useEffect(() => {
   setLoading(true); // If you want to add loader or spinner till companies info fetched
   const connectionsPromises = connections.map((connection) => {
     return VolunteerApi.getCurrentCompany(connection);
   });

   Promise.all(connectionsPromises).then((companies) => {
      setCompany(companies); // save companies 
      setLoading(false); // disable loader 
   });
}, [connections])
```

Promise.all resolves promises parallelly

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can only use hooks at the top level of your component.

Take a look at [the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) (including useEffect).

You should try to put your `if` and `for` loop inside the `useEffect`.